# Deploying SSIS (SQL Server 2012) Project Outside Network

Tags: deployment, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have built an SSIS project on my PC, and am connecting to an SQL 2012 Server outside our network (via SQL Authentication) while executing the package.  It is now time to deploy the project to that same server, but I have hit a wall.  While going through the built-in deployment wizard, I enter the Server Name (just as I have entered it to connect to the database withing the connection managers) and get an “untrusted domain” error (it is requiring Window’s Authentication rather than SQL Authentication).

I think it may also be relevant that I am using parameters to set environment-specific values in the project.

How do I deploy an SSIS project to a SQL Server outside the network?

I should also add that in my searches, I did come across someone who was struggling to do this with a VPN connection (with no resolution posted), is that how this is typically done?

Comment: Could this be a DNS problem? ie the server name internally is different from the externally published name?

Comment: Project deployment model (new) or package deployment (legacy)?

Comment: @Bill: Thanks for the input.  Wouldn't  I have to use the external name to deploy from my local machine (with the SQL Server being outside the network)?

Comment: @billinkc: My understanding is that given the fact that I am using parameters, I need to use the Project Deployment.  I don't have a preference otherwise.  Only one of the packages from the project will be executing on the server, so if I can use package deployment I am happy to do so.

Answer (score 10):

You've got 3 tools for deploying .ispac files into the SSISDB catalog.

1. ISDeploymentWizard.exe
2. [ManagedObjectModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.aspx)
3. TSQL

You are already using the wizard and it's not working due to auth issues. I think even with your MOM approach, you'll still run into auth issues. That leaves the TSQL approach and since you have a valid logon, hopefully this will work.

The following code will serialize your .ispac, create the deployment folder if it does not already exist, deploy the project and then assign a parameter value.

In SSMS, you will need to change your mode to SQLCMD mode which is available under the Query menu. After doing that, hit Ctrl-Shift-M to bring up the macro-thing and it will allow you to specify where the .ispac file can be found.

```
USE SSISDB
GO

IF ('$(isPacPath)' = '$' + '(isPacPath)')
BEGIN
    THROW 50000, N'This script must be run in SQLCMD mode.', 1;
END
GO

-- You must be in SQLCMD mode
-- setvar isPacPath "C:\sandbox\SSDTDeploy\TSQLDeploy\bin\Development\TSQLDeploy.ispac"
:setvar isPacPath "<isPacFilePath, nvarchar(4000), C:\sandbox\SSDTDeploy\TSQLDeploy\bin\Development\TSQLDeploy.ispac>"



DECLARE
    @folder_name nvarchar(128) = 'TSQLDeploy'
,   @folder_id bigint = NULL
    -- this must match the ispac
,   @project_name nvarchar(128) = 'TSQLDeploy'
,   @project_stream varbinary(max)
,   @operation_id bigint = NULL;

-- Read the zip (ispac) data in from the source file
SELECT
    @project_stream = T.stream
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(BULK N'$(isPacPath)', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS B
) AS T (stream);

-- Test for catalog existences
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        CF.name
    FROM
        catalog.folders AS CF
    WHERE
        CF.name = @folder_name
)
BEGIN
    -- Create the folder for our project
    EXECUTE [catalog].[create_folder] 
        @folder_name
    ,   @folder_id OUTPUT;
END

-- Actually deploy the project
EXECUTE [catalog].[deploy_project] 
    @folder_name
,   @project_name
,   @project_stream
,   @operation_id OUTPUT;

-- Check to see if something went awry
SELECT
    OM.* 
FROM
    catalog.operation_messages AS OM;

-- Use this to set parameters
-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878162.aspx
EXECUTE catalog.set_object_parameter_value 
    -- Use the value 20 to indicate a project parameter 
    -- or the value 30 to indicate a package parameter
    @object_type = 20 
,   @folder_name = @folder_name
,   @project_name = @project_name
,   @parameter_name = N'' -- nvarchar(128)
,   @parameter_value = NULL -- sql_variant
,   @object_name = N'' -- nvarchar(260)
,   @value_type = '' -- char(1)
--  Use the character V to indicate that parameter_value is a literal value 
-- that will be used by default if no other values are assigned prior 
-- to execution. 
-- Use the character R to indicate that parameter_value is a referenced value 
-- and has been set to the name of an environment variable. 
-- This argument is optional, the character V is used by default
```

If you attended the SQL Pass Summit 2012 conference, I demoed this in my talk on the [2012 Deployment Model](http://www.sqlpass.org/summit/2012/Sessions/SessionDetails.aspx?sid=3794) but I didn't cover the [parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878162.aspx) part. I believe that last call to be correct but I have not verified it. I have linked to the documentation for the procedure call so that you can tailor it to your specific needs.

Sample [PowerShell implementation](https://gist.github.com/billinkc/64d2168964a6f15d45bc)

### Update August 2013

I've learned something at my current client. We have our laptops which are joined to the home domain. We have accounts on the client's AD network. Whenever I need to "do" something in the client's world, I need to launch my process and instruct it to present my "foreign" credentials. What makes this possible is [RunAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx). Alternate [reference](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html)

I created a suite of batch files that launch every process I need. They take the form of

```
runas /netonly:ForeignDomain\Doppelganger "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
```

I have one for a command prompt (above), Visual Studio, SSMS, PowerShell, PowerShell ISE and some other specialty apps that need to work with their domain.

Using the runas approach, I've been able to deploy packages using all of the above methods (as well as deploying directly from a Visual Studio instance being run with foreign credentials).

Comment: Thank you very much.  I copied your code into a SQLCMD mode query window, replaced the ispac file location (I also moved the setvar isPacPath statement to the top to get rid of an undefined variable error).  When executing that query I get a "Cannot bulk load because file...could not be opened.  Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.)"  I can paste the same location into windows explorer and it opens the deployment wizard, so it is valid.  I am leaving for vacation in a matter of hours but will follow up with your advice as soon as I return.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sounds like progress. This might still come down to a SQL user trying to reach out into the filesystem and the OS would need to know who that thing is. *shrug* Anyways, enjoy your holiday, look forward to resolving this.

Comment: I just couldn't get this working (i.e., couldn't figure out why it wasn't finding the file), so I ended up creating a new project with the same parameter settings on the server, then copying the package files to the server and importing the packages into the new project.  Not elegant, but it worked.  Thanks again

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the edit I made would have resolved your problem. The runas command would have allowed you to talk to the remote domain passing the foreign credentials.

Comment: almost all stored procs in [catalog] require AD authentication, not sql server authentication; this may impact the feasibility of some deployment models

Answer (score 6):

One way that i've used when faced with a similar issue is:

1. Built the project in VS 2012.
2. Copy the "*.ispac" file to the Remote Server.
3. Double Click on the "*.ispac" ,run the wizard by selecting the destination server and catalogs.
4. Connect with a Windows Account having required Access level and roles, validate the package.

The only issue is that if you have multiple parameters and your packages are encrypted you won't be able to import it(This from the warning message being displayed ,i've not tested with and encrypted package).

Hope it helps.

Comment: This way appears to be much more straightforward, it works well