# Deploying SSIS (SQL Server 2012) Project to remote SQL Server

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS project build by SSDT-BI 2012 and it is a project development model project.

I try to deploy the project to remote SQL Server standard edition thought SSDT-BI.

But the wizard doesn't let me input username and password for SQL authorization.

I read [a SOF post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463839/deploying-ssis-sql-server-2012-project-outside-network) said copy the *.ispac file from /bin folder to remote server file system to do so.

Unfortunately, the server do not allow RDP access.

So any solution?

[image]

Comment: Can you access this server from SSMS under your user account (not using SQL Server Authentication)?